# Calling javascript function defined on the child window from parent window EXTJS

Tags: extjs, window, modal-dialog

I have a EXTJS modal window. I would like to call a function defined on the child window from the parent window every time child window gets displayed. Is it possible to call child window function from parent window in EXTJS modal window. Thanks.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    if (! mywindow){
        // create the window on the first click and reuse on subsequent clicks
        mywindow = new Ext.Window({
            title: 'My Modal Winow',
            closable:true,
            closeAction:'hide',
            width:600,
            height:350,
            border:false,
            maximizable: true,
            plain:true,
            layout: 'border',
            id : 'mywindowid',
            html  : '< div id="userframe"><iframe style="overflow:auto;width:100% height:100%;" frameborder="0" id="mrgraphiframe" src="' + customurl + '"></iframe></div >'

 ,listeners : {
         show: myfunction(){}
              }// end of listner
        });
    }        
    mywindow.show(this);
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you want to achieve? I must admit that I didn't get it yet.

Comment: Ok, here is what I am trying to do. On Page 1(parent html page). I am calling a function to open a modal window which is of type iframe. On the target iframe I have a user defined function say myfunction. I would like to call this myfunction from the parent window. So on mywindow.show event I would like to call myfunction which is defined on the target iframe. I am not sure how to access functions defined on the target frame of modal window from parent window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to execute whenever the window is shown, just attach an event listener to it..

```
listeners : {
    show: functionToCall
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry if my question was not clear. I am trying to execute a function which is defined in the child modal window. When I call a function defined in the child window from parent window it throw javascript error saying object expect. Is there a way to call a function from parent window just like we call javascript:window.parent.functionname(). Thanks.

Comment: no, because the modal window is still in the same dom. The only way around it would be to create the function in a global scope and that way you can call it from anywhere